# How to Prevent Drop down to show values that is in Database

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to prevent the value of the dropdown list when it is already in the database file so that theres no multiple input in the Database ,

I hope someone can Help me with this problem ,

I'm using MVC 3 and Kendo UI

is that possible to handle it via Jquery or a Linq Statement in the Controller ?

Thanks :)

```
 <span>
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlDay", new SelectList(ViewBag.DayList, "ID", "Display_Value", PersonDay), "[Please Select]",
          new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
                })
            </span>
```

This Dropdown Show Monday to Sunday , i have 2 of this drop down that shows availability But i like to know that if i save Monday to Wednesday , Monday to Wednesday is removed on the two dropdowns ,

```
private void GetDayList()
        {
            var dayList = (from a in db.Lookups
                              where a.Domain == "DAYSTATUS"
                              select a).ToList();

            ViewBag.DayList = dayList ;
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  I am not sure what you are asking for.. how is the Dropdown populated?

Comment: Please post the markup and binding code for the drop down list.

Comment: @Robert Question Updated

Comment: @KarlAnderson Question Updated

Comment: Okay, please post the code that populates the `ViewBag.DayList`.

Comment: And finally, please post the logic to save a drop down list choice in the view.

Comment: Your posted code is not enough to give an example code but i think you can check whether the values exists on the database before binding it to the dropdown? You can use the LINQ query inside GetDayList() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in many ways, it will depend on how your interaction is done.

You could use LINQ, adding a Where() or Except() statement to filter the full list:

```
var fromDayList = dayList.Where(day => day.Name != selectedFromDay).ToList();
// or if multiple selected days, assuming it is of the same type:
var validDayList = dayList.Except(selectedDayList).ToList();
```

If you allow them to change the selected days client side and are using AJAX (which is how you usually use Kendo UI) then you won't want to filter server side. Instead you should wrap your `DayList` in a `kendo.DataSource` and apply a filter based on selected days in your JavaScript. You haven't provided enough information for me to supply any sample code for this.

Comment: how can i add the `selectedFromDay`

Comment: I can only assume it is a property of your Model, in which case from the Controller you would use `Model.SelectedFromDay`. Looking at what you're doing though, you don't seem to be using a Model, just tossing everything in the ViewBag. Seriously consider that MVC is Model-View-Controller, a Model is very important.

Comment: I have model and i pass the value in an Info.cs before passing it to the view . ..

Comment: Why are you using the ViewBag if you have a Model? I would expect your Model for this page would have at least the following properties (assuming server-side filtering): FromDayList, ToDayList, FromDay, ToDay, plus any other info you need for input and/or display. When creating this model it would retrieve and filter information from the database as needed.

Comment: so what do you think , do i need to include it to `private void GetDayList()` ? Thanks

Comment: With the limited information you have provided, it is hard to say. Why don't you try it and see if it works for you?